# How to destroy an AIDL stub?

Tags: android, android-service, aidl

I have a service with AIDL interfaces like this:

```
interface Bar {

    void doStuff();
    // ...
    void destroySelf();
}

interface Foo {

    // ...
    Bar createBar();
}
```

In the service implementation, the `Foo` stub maintains a list of created `Bar` stubs and in the `Bar` stub, when `destroySelf()` is called, this instance is removed from the list.

I want the destroyed `Bar` instance to be not callable anymore by the clients, how do I do that?

This client code doesn't throw any exception:

```
Bar bar = foo.createBar();
bar.destroySelf();
bar.doStuff();  //I want that to go "boom"
```

I've looked at the `Binder` implementation and there is a `destroy()` native method that is called from the `finalize()` method, but that is called only when the garbage collector decides to wake up. I'm not even sure that the `Binder` stuff doesn't keep a reference to the `BarStub` instances to be able to access them when a client calls a method on one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right when you say that the Binder stuff keeps a reference to the `BarStub` instance to be able to access them whenever. Effectively, Binder objects are garbage-collected system-wide, so they only cease to exist when no process has access to them.

I'd suggest two options:

- Don't think of `destroySelf()` as something which actually destroys the object, but instead puts it into a state where it is inactive. Then, in all other method calls (e.g. `doStuff()`) check the state of the object and return an error if the object is in an inactive state.
- Better still, work *with* the design of Android Binder instead of against it. The cross-process reference counting is probably just what you want. Specifically, I'd do this:

  - Remove `destroySelf()`
  - Within the service, don't keep a reference to the `Bar`.
  - If the service really knows that the `Bar` has been destroyed you can call `linkToDeath` on it. But, I don't believe you can keep a reference to it otherwise or it will never be destroyed.

Comment: Option 2 is a no-go. On the service side, the business logic forces me to know the list of `BarStub` instanciated from the `FooStub` instance. So `destroySelf` is needed.